# Actionscript - make nested fixed length Vector

Tags: actionscript-3, vector

I want to make a nested Vector, where i define the length of the nested vector too, someting like this:

```
var kb:Vector.<Vector.<Number>> = new Vector.<Vector.<Number>(4)>(4); // 4x4 vector
```

This line throws a compilation error - anyone knows, if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of a `Vector` is set by a *constructor* argument. By using generics (type in angle brackets) you can only say that this vector is containing vectors with numbers, like this:

```
var outer:Vector.<Vector.<Number>> = new Vector.<Vector.<Number>>(4);
```

The size of nested vectors cannot be limited here since they aren't initialized. When initializing a vector which will be nested, you can do this:

```
var inner:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>(4);
```

You could also check the length of a nested vector by overriding every manipulating method of the `Vector` class within a custom class where you check for the pushed vector's length.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i dislike the AS3 Vector class more and more.. In C++ the vector class is much better, for example vector< vector<double> > kb(4,vector<double>(4,8)); creates a 4x4 vector which is filled with 8s, and i AS3 i need to write a helper function